# Ubuntu/Linux configuration file usage convention

Tags: configuration, etc

I have been using Ubuntu Linux occasionally for some time. I know the `/etc` folder is for configuration files. But I have always found 2 things difficult:

1. Find the correct configuration file to modify for a specific scenario.
2. Map the configuration GUI to the backend configuration file in the `/etc` folder so I can script it next time.

So, my quetsions are:

1. Once I install a new pacakge, how can I find all its configuration files?
2. What's the usage convention of the numerous configuration files in `/etc` folder? Is there some catagorization schema such as folder for network configuration, folder for user management configuration, etc.?
3. Is it possible for some configuration files live outside the `/etc` folder?

Thanks and pardon me if this is a naive question.

Answer (score 2):

> Once I install a new pacakge, how can I find all its configuration files?

Run `dpkg -L package-name` and see which files the package contains in `/etc` (which should all be configuration files). Look in the package documentation and manpages for any other configuration files it may use.

> What's the usage convention of the numerous configuration files in /etc folder? Is there some catagorization schema such as folder for network configuration, folder for user management configuration, etc.?

Usually, `/etc/<program-name>.conf` or `/etc/<program-name>.d`. It could be anything (for example, `/etc/NetworkManager`, `/etc/wgetrc`).

> Is it possible for some configuration files live outside the /etc folder?

Certainly. Though convention is for configuration to be in `/etc`, configuration that is not supposed to be edited by users/administrators can be elsewhere. For example, `/lib/systemd/system` contains all the systemd units from packages (whereas Upstart jobs would be in `/etc/init`).